# How to add target to keyboard done/go/search buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, action, addtarget

I want to attach a action to button, which is on keyboard. I don't want to create a custom keyboard, only handle search/go/done buttons actions.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

To handle return Key you  Use delegate `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         // your Action According to your textfield
        return true
    }
```

How to change Return Key

```
yourTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.search
yourTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
```

**Apple Enum :**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIReturnKeyType) {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
    UIReturnKeyContinue NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn` to get that button tapped event, irrespectively of the name of the button.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //conform protocol of `UITextFieldDelegate` in any of `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method
    self.textFieldYouWantToHandle.delegate = self;

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == textFieldYouWantToHandle {
           //any task to perform
           textField.resignFirstResponder() //if you want to dismiss your keyboard
        }
        return true
    }
}
```